# HTML5, autocomplete: How to combine postal-code and address-level2 in one single text field?

Tags: html, autocomplete, autofill

I have an online shop with a checkout form for typing in your name, address, and contact data.

The HTML5 `autocomplete` tags generally work for Chrome/Android users, but unfortunately, there is one text field for postal code and city combined in one field (for example, "10559 Berlin").

It seems that I can only tag this field with `autocomplete='postal-code'` or `autocomplete='address-level2'`, but not both together in one field, so `autocomplete='postal-code address-level2'` makes Chrome insert only the city when autofill is used, but not the postal code. I'm also assuming that it goes vice versa the other way around (i.e. `autocomplete='address-level2 postal-code` would make Chrome fill in the postal code only.

Does anybody maybe know how to use both of these two autocomplete detail tokens into one single field with one `autocomplete` attribute?

Comment: You can't use both autocompletes in the same `input` box, but you can make 2 `input` boxes look and function like one -- see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43520644/5463636) below for an example.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible to do - in this way.

There are other ways like autofill city with postal code, my guess would be to do it the other way - to **autofill postal code with given city/village** etc. because its often the case that many villages have the same number (and also the same street names)!

You would go and listen `oninput` for the specific `input` field and add the postal code after the city is inserted so go for `autocomplete="address-level2"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get really hacky, you could make it look like one input box, but each has its own `autocomplete` tag and it would automatically switch boxes when a space is typed or when the user tabs after selecting a value from the autofill list.

See this example:

```js
var zipInput = document.getElementById('zipInput');
var cityInput = document.getElementById('cityInput');

zipInput.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  if (zipInput.value.slice(-1) != " ") {
    return;
  }
  var text = zipInput.value.split(" ")[0];
  cityInput.focus();
});

zipInput.focus();
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#zipInput {
  border-right: none;
  width: 75px;
}

#cityInput {
  border-left: none;
  width: 125px;
}
```

```html
<h4>Postal Code & City:</h4>
<form onsubmit="javascript: return false;">
  <input id="zipInput" autocomplete='postal code'><input id="cityInput" autocomplete='address-level2'>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello my German friends ;-)

Finally, I decided to separate the combined field for postal code and city into two fields, one for postal code and one for city. So I can use a single autocomplete token for each one, although the separation caused some changes also on other places within the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible but you can use an ugly trick. put the second input text anywhere in the site the user can't see :)

here is my jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vm2ugpr6/11/)

```
Address: <input type="text" id="autocomp" value=""  autocomplete="postal-code">
<input id="hid" type ="text" value="" autocomplete="locality" onchange="change()">

<script>

function change () {
var a = document.getElementById("hid").value;
var b = document.getElementById("autocomp").value;
var c = b + " " +a;
document.getElementById("autocomp").value = c;
}

</script>
```

in this example is the id="hid" is the second input field. (display : none is not working)